# Test if object was properly created

Tags: java, unit-testing

I'm putting more attention into unit tests these days and I got in a situation for which I'm not sure how to make a good test.

I have a function which creates and returns an object of class X. This X class is part of the framework, so I'm not very familiar with it's implementation and I don't have freedom as in the case of my "regular collaborator classes" (the ones which I have written). Also, when I pass some arguments I cannot check if object X is set to right parameters and I'm not able to pass mock in some cases.

My question is - how to check if this object was properly created, that is, to check which parameters were passed to its constructor? And how to avoid problem when constructor throws an exception when I pass a mock?

Maybe I'm not clear enough, here is a snippet:

```
public class InputSplitCreator {

Table table;
Scan scan;
RegionLocator regionLocator;


public InputSplitCreator(Table table, Scan scan, RegionLocator regionLocator) {

    this.table = table;
    this.scan = scan;
    this.regionLocator = regionLocator;
}

public InputSplit getInputSplit(String scanStart, String scanStop, Pair<byte[][], byte[][]> startEndKeys, int i) {

    String start = Bytes.toString(startEndKeys.getFirst()[i]);
    String end = Bytes.toString(startEndKeys.getSecond()[i]);

    String startSalt;

    if (start.length() == 0)
        startSalt = "0";
    else
        startSalt = start.substring(0, 1);

    byte[] startRowKey = Bytes.toBytes(startSalt + "-" + scanStart);
    byte[] endRowKey = Bytes.toBytes(startSalt + "-" + scanStop);

    TableSplit tableSplit;

    try {

        HRegionLocation regionLocation = regionLocator.getRegionLocation(startEndKeys.getFirst()[i]);
        String hostnamePort = regionLocation.getHostnamePort();

        tableSplit = new TableSplit(table.getName(), scan, startRowKey, endRowKey, hostnamePort);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        throw new HBaseRetrievalException("Problem while trying to find region location for region " + i, ex);
    }

    return tableSplit;
}
```

}

So, this creates an InputSplit. I would like to know whether this split is created with correct parameters. How to do that?

Comment: can you show us the code, because it's not really clear

Answer (score 1):

If the class is part of a framework, then you shouldn't test it directly, as the framework has tested it for you. If you *still* want to test the behaviour of this object, look at the cause-reaction this object would cause. More specifically: mock the object, have it do stuff and check if the affected objects (which you can control) carry out the expected behaviour or are in the correct state.

For more details you should probably update your answer with the framework you're using and the class of said framework you wish to test

Comment: Maybe I'm misinterpreting you, but it sounds like you're saying "don't test it" and "mock it and test the mock" at the same time?

Comment: I'm missing a keyword here: "If you *still* want to test it..."

Comment: Can you please reconsider my question, I have added an example?

Answer (score 0):

This is possibly one of those cases where you shouldn't be testing it directly. This object is supposedly USED for something, yes? If it's not created correctly, some part of your code will break, no?

At some point or another, your application depends on this created object to behave in a certain way, so you can test it implicitly by testing that these procedures that depend on it are working correctly.

This can save you from coupling more abstract use cases from the internal workings and types of the framework.

Comment: Can you please reconsider my question, I have added an example?